# How to deal with a bad performance review (that I never knew existed) which caused me to not get a raise

Tags: salary

I work for a very large global company. With the recommendation of my new boss, I recently asked my company to look into all my reviews to see if my pay is in line with my having worked for the company for 5 years. I found out that my old boss (who has since been fired) gave me a terrible review less than a month after she took over our store and that review prevented me from getting a pay increase. I knew nothing about this review until my company responded to my inquiry.

My question is: what are my rights to get back pay?

Comment: The company pays you what it thinks you are worth. If they thought your old boss treated you harshly, they would have made amends. The fact that they didn't tells you all you need to know.

Comment: I can't see you getting this resolved in your favour

Comment: You look for a new company to work in. That's usually the fastest way to get pay raises, especially the current way your company is treating you right now.

Answer (score 6):

You have no "rights".

You can ask HR whether the fact that you didn't know about the evaluation makes any difference under company policy. It probably won't.

You can ask your current management to review that evaluation. But even if they agree to do so, they may not want to or be able to change the salary outcome.

Your best bet, really, is to learn from the experience and make sure you understand how and when your company does evaluations and how much input you are supposed to have into the process.

Understand what you were badly reviewed on and make a plan to address it. Ask your manager whether there are other skills you need to work on in order to qualify for a raise, and address those. If they don't give you good feedback automatically, take responsibility for asking for guidance. In the end, nobody cares as much about advancing your career as you do, and if it isn't happening you need to make it happen.

The company is under no obligation to do anything about this even if they agree the former boss was unfair. They could backdate a raise, but you have no ability to demand they do so unless you can prove that this was a civil rights issue that you are willing to take to court, and/or are seriously willing to quit over it. Either could be a career-limiting action, so think long and hard before acting. The best I think you're likely to get, if they overturn the past decision, is a bit more on your next raise to bring you up to the pay band you would be in if this hadn't happened... and frankly I think you should be surprised and grateful if they do that much.

Comment: I've been in a similar situation where issues discussed in reviews were never brought to my attention at any other point. The OP has to make a decision based on what the company is asking him to do (do they "trust" him with work but giving poor reviews?) and then make an informed decision as to leaving and securing a new job with proper pay.

Comment: My current boss realized that my former boss was devious in doing a review but never sharing. As I am an exemplary employee, this review had I known about it, would never have been forwarded to HR. Anyway, from looking into my files my current boss noticed that I am not making enough so I did get a raise  My question is whether it should hv been back paid to 2012 when the bogus review was made.

Comment: Added another paragraph to  clarify that back pay is extremely unlikely unless you are willing to play you-bet-your-job.

Comment: @user49251: The answer to back pay is no.  Retroactively changing someone's pay is pretty rare and, as keshlam pointed at, they are under no obligation to do so unless it was due to some form of provable discrimination.  Simply having a previous crap manager that threw you under a bus doesn't qualify.